# Controlling NUnit output in Resharper 'Unit Test Sessions' window

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I'm attempting to polish some unit tests, and I'm noticing that NUnit's output behaves in an undesirable way; I'm wondering if I have any ability to control it.

Consider the following `OneTimeSetUp`

```
Imports NUnit.Framework

Public Class SimpleInconclusive
    <OneTimeSetUp>
    Public Sub OneTimeSetUp()
         Assert.Inconclusive("Why do I print twice?")
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I inherit from this class in any test fixture, the output does not behave as desired.

Consider this simple sample

```
[TestFixture]
class Class1 : SimpleInconclusive
{
    [Test]
    public void MySimpleTest()
    {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

[image: The fixture output displays the inconclusive report for each test, rather than once for the whole fixture.]

[image: The test output does not display in the output window.]

Rather frustrating, as this clutters the window meant to provide easily-actionable messages.

Can I correct this to behave intuitively, where the output window only shows me the output for the test/fixture that is highlighted, rather than one aggregate message repeating the same message multiple times?

Comment: As best I can figure out from google, the window you are displaying is from Resharper. Please label accordingly as I'll never get back those 5 minutes of research to determine I can't help you. :-(

Comment: Sorry, @Charlie, my mistake!